# using "Not equal" operator in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently working on a small macro that inserts a row if one of the following columns are a different number. I have the below peice of code but cannot understan why this isn't working.

Could anyone point out my mistake?

```
Sub Button1_Click()

Dim rowCount As Integer
rowCount = 10

If cell(rowCount, 2) <> cell((rowCount + 1), 2) Then
    Rows(rowCount).Insert
    rowCount = rowCount + 2
ElseIf cell(rowCount, 2) = cell((rowCount + 1), 2) Then
    rowCount = rowCount + 1

End Sub
```

Comment: `cell` is not defined.

Comment: as an aside `rowCount` will not increment between calls of this sub.

Comment: Where is the `EndIf` and why not just `Else`, but have `ElseIf`?

Comment: [edit] the question and make it valid syntax and also explain _how_ it is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `cell` is neither defined nor `Set`... use `Cells`.
- It's best to be explicit: add the `.Value` to indicate you are comparing values.
- Use a simple `Else` instead of `ElseIf...` and include the `End If`.

```
If Cells(rowCount, 2).Value <> Cells((rowCount + 1), 2).Value Then
    Rows(rowCount).Insert
    rowCount = rowCount + 2
Else
    rowCount = rowCount + 1
End If
```

P.S. Do not use `Integer` for tracking rows, but use `Long` instead *always*. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409117/why-use-integer-instead-of-long) for the full detail.

P.P.S. *Always* use `Option Explicit`, which would flag the undeclared variable `cell`.

Comment: Agree with comments but it does not implies a down vote as attested by the OP satisfaction. JAlex spent time helping and deserves a thank you.